# WebSocket - Соединение закрыто: Код - 1006

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, websocket

У нас есть WebSocket сервер в котором с python и nodejs (я думаю с любого бэка) можно подключиться и все работает как было задумано. Но с фронта (react js, vanilajs) ошибка (Соединение закрыто: Код - 1006, Причина - ) остальные ошибки можно посмотреть в скрине.
в сервер отправляется botName и botToken через Sec-WebSocket-Protocol.

```
const ws = new WebSocket("ws://147.45.107.29:8090/ws/battle", [
       "frildev1",
      "4da2939c-98e5-44f8-be27-f79392497ffa",
     ]);
```

frildev1 - botName
4da2939c-98e5-44f8-be27-f79392497ffa - botToken

попробовали даже так

```
const botName = "frildev1";
const token = "4da2939c-98e5-44f8-be27-f79392497ffa";

    // Кодируем токен в формате base64url
    const encodedToken = btoa(token)
      .replace(/\+/g, "-")
      .replace(/\//g, "_")
      .replace(/=/g, "");

    // Формируем подпротокол для аутентификации с токеном
    const subprotocol = "base64url.bearer.authorization.k8s.io." + encodedToken;

    // Создаем WebSocket соединение с указанием подпротокола аутентификации и имени бота
    const ws = new WebSocket("ws://147.45.107.29:8090/ws/battle", [
      botName,
      subprotocol,
    ]);
```

В чем может быть причина этой ошибки ? В сервере проблем нет, так-как с того же нод и питон можно без проблем подключиться и все работает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если соединение через sec, почему протокол ws?

Comment: @SwaD
Извиняюсь, соединения через WebSocket. а отправка headers через Sec-WebSocket-Protocol